# как сделать кнопку не активной?

Tags: python, ui, pyqt6

есть две кнопки, одна расчет, вторая вывод графика. Как сделать кнопку вывода графика не активной до того пока не будет сделан расчет? расчет идет по двум выбираемым параметрам. и например сделан расчет по одному параметру и по нему же строится график, а если переключаем на второй параметр и нажимаем кнопку вывода графика то он идет по первому расчету. Надеюсь понятно объяснил. У меня две программы, одна по алгоритму, вторая по интерфейсу, интерфейс делал в qt designer ui формат. Библиотtка PyQT6
Код алгоритма:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from interface20 import *    #интерфейс
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import math
from matplotlib import mlab
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib.patches import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
from bisect import bisect_left

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

def soplo_profil(): 
 
    def bell_nozzle(k, aratio, Rt, l_percent):                                          # вычисления геометрических параметров сопла 
        entrant_angle   = -135                                                          # upto the nozzle designer, usually -135
        ea_radian       = math.radians(entrant_angle)
        l_percent = 80                                                                  # nozzle length percntage upto the nozzle designer, usually 80
        Lnp = 0.8

        angles = find_wall_angles(aratio, throat_radius, l_percent)                     # find wall angles (theta_n, theta_e) for given aratio (ar)     
        nozzle_length = angles[0]; theta_n = angles[1]; theta_e = angles[2];

        data_intervel   = 100
        # throat entrant section / скругление входа в критику
        ea_start        = ea_radian                                                     # where: −135 ≤ θ ≤ −90 (The initial angle is typical -135 degrees)
        ea_end          = -math.pi/2                                                    # where: −135 ≤ θ ≤ −90
        angle_list      = np.linspace(ea_start, ea_end, data_intervel)
        xe = []; ye = [];
        for i in angle_list:
            xe.append( 1.5 * Rt * math.cos(i) )
            ye.append( 1.5 * Rt * math.sin(i) + 2.5 * Rt )

        #exit section / скругление выхода из критики
        ea_start        = -math.pi/2                # where: −90 ≤ θ ≤ (θn − 90)
        ea_end          = theta_n - math.pi/2       # where: −90 ≤ θ ≤ (θn − 90)
        angle_list      = np.linspace(ea_start, ea_end, data_intervel)  
        xe2 = []; ye2 = [];
        for i in angle_list:
            xe2.append( 0.382 * Rt * math.cos(i) )
            ye2.append( 0.382 * Rt * math.sin(i) + 1.382 * Rt )

        # bell section / параболическая секция 
        Nx = 0.382 * Rt * math.cos(theta_n - math.pi/2)                                 # Nx, Ny-N is defined by [Eqn. 5] setting the angle to (θn – 90)
        Ny = 0.382 * Rt * math.sin(theta_n - math.pi/2) + 1.382 * Rt                    # Nx, Ny-N is defined by [Eqn. 5] setting the angle to (θn – 90)
        Ex = Lnp * ( (math.sqrt(aratio) - 1) * Rt )/ math.tan(math.radians(15) )        # Ex - [Eqn. 3], and coordinate Ey - [Eqn. 2]
        Ey = math.sqrt(aratio) * Rt                                                     # Ex - [Eqn. 3], and coordinate Ey - [Eqn. 2]
        m1 = math.tan(theta_n);  m2 = math.tan(theta_e);                                # gradient m1,m2 - [Eqn. 8]
        C1 = Ny - m1*Nx;  C2 = Ey - m2*Ex;                                              # intercept - [Eqn. 9]
        Qx = (C2 - C1)/(m1 - m2)                                                        # intersection of these two lines (at point Q)-[Eqn.10]
        Qy = (m1*C2 - m2*C1)/(m1 - m2)                                                  # intersection of these two lines (at point Q)-[Eqn.10]
        
        int_list = np.linspace(0, 1, data_intervel)
        xbell = []; ybell = [];
        for t in int_list:                                                              # the bell is a quadratic Bézier curve, which has equations
            xbell.append( ((1-t)**2)*Nx + 2*(1-t)*t*Qx + (t**2)*Ex )
            ybell.append( ((1-t)**2)*Ny + 2*(1-t)*t*Qy + (t**2)*Ey )
        
        # create negative values for the other half of nozzle / создание значений для второй половины профиля
        nye     = [ -y for y in ye]
        nye2    = [ -y for y in ye2]
        nybell  = [ -y for y in ybell]
        return angles, (xe, ye, nye, xe2, ye2, nye2, xbell, ybell, nybell)      

    def find_wall_angles(ar, Rt, l_percent):                                            # определение углов θn и θe в зависимости от aratio по графикам эмпирических данных 
        aratio      = [ 4,    5,    10,   20,   30,   40,   50,   100]
        theta_n_60  = [20.5, 20.5, 16.0, 14.5, 14.0, 13.5, 13.0, 11.2]
        theta_n_80  = [21.5, 23.0, 26.3, 28.8, 30.0, 31.0, 31.5, 33.5]
        theta_n_90  = [20.0, 21.0, 24.0, 27.0, 28.5, 29.5, 30.2, 32.0]
        theta_e_60  = [26.5, 28.0, 32.0, 35.0, 36.2, 37.1, 35.0, 40.0]
        theta_e_80  = [14.0, 13.0, 11.0,  9.0,  8.5,  8.0,  7.5,  7.0]
        theta_e_90  = [11.5, 10.5,  8.0,  7.0,  6.5,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0]  

        # nozzle length / длина сопла
        f1 = ( (math.sqrt(ar) - 1) * Rt )/ math.tan(math.radians(15) )
        theta_n = theta_n_80; theta_e = theta_e_80;
        Ln = 0.8 * f1       

        global len_nozzle
        len_nozzle = Ln

        # find the nearest ar index in the aratio list
        x_index, x_val = find_nearest(aratio, ar)
        # if the value at the index is close to input, return it
        if round(aratio[x_index], 1) == round(ar, 1):
            return Ln, math.radians(theta_n[x_index]), math.radians(theta_e[x_index])

        # check where the index lies, and slice accordingly
        if (x_index>2):
            # slice couple of middle values for interpolation
            ar_slice = aratio[x_index-2:x_index+2]      
            tn_slice = theta_n[x_index-2:x_index+2]
            te_slice = theta_e[x_index-2:x_index+2]
            # find the tn_val for given ar
            tn_val = interpolate(ar_slice, tn_slice, ar)    
            te_val = interpolate(ar_slice, te_slice, ar)    
        elif( (len(aratio)-x_index) <= 1):
            # slice couple of values initial for interpolation
            ar_slice = aratio[x_index-2:len(x_index)]       
            tn_slice = theta_n[x_index-2:len(x_index)]
            te_slice = theta_e[x_index-2:len(x_index)]
            # find the tn_val for given ar
            tn_val = interpolate(ar_slice, tn_slice, ar)    
            te_val = interpolate(ar_slice, te_slice, ar)    
        else:
            # slice couple of end values for interpolation
            ar_slice = aratio[0:x_index+2]      
            tn_slice = theta_n[0:x_index+2]
            te_slice = theta_e[0:x_index+2]
            # find the tn_val for given ar
            tn_val = interpolate(ar_slice, tn_slice, ar)    
            te_val = interpolate(ar_slice, te_slice, ar)                        
        return Ln, math.radians(tn_val), math.radians(te_val)   

    def interpolate(x_list, y_list, x):                                                 # функция интерполяции для определения углов θn и θe по графикам эмпирических данных 
        if any(y - x <= 0 for x, y in zip(x_list, x_list[1:])):
            raise ValueError("x_list must be in strictly ascending order!")
        intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])
        slopes = [(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) for x1, x2, y1, y2 in intervals]

        if x <= x_list[0]:
            return y_list[0]
        elif x >= x_list[-1]:
            return y_list[-1]
        else:
            i = bisect_left(x_list, x) - 1
            return y_list[i] + slopes[i] * (x - x_list[i])                                              

    def find_nearest(array, value):                                                     # функция поиска ближайшего значения для определения углов θn и θe по графикам эмпирических данных 
        array = np.asarray(array)
        idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
        return idx, array[idx]  

    def plot_nozzle(ax, title, Rt, angles, contour):                                    # построение профиля сопла с размерами 
        # wall angles
        nozzle_length = angles[0]; theta_n = angles[1]; theta_e = angles[2];
        
        # contour values
        xe = contour[0];    ye = contour[1];    nye = contour[2];
        xe2 = contour[3];   ye2 = contour[4];   nye2 = contour[5];
        xbell = contour[6]; ybell = contour[7]; nybell = contour[8];
        
        # set correct aspect ratio
        ax.set_aspect('equal')

        # throat enterant
        ax.plot(xe, ye, linewidth=2.5, color='g')
        ax.plot(xe, nye, linewidth=2.5, color='g')
        
        # chamder exit
        Sx = xe[0]
        Sy = ye[0]
        Sny = nye[0]
        Ex = Sx - (R - Sy)
        Ey = R
        Eny = -R
        linex = [Sx, Ex]
        liney = [Sy, Ey]
        lineny = [Sny, Eny]
        ax.plot(linex, liney, linewidth=2.5, color='k')         # выход из камеры сгорания
        ax.plot(linex, lineny, linewidth=2.5, color='k')        # выход из камеры сгорания

        # throat inlet line
        x1 = linex[1]; y1 = 0;
        x2 = linex[1]; y2 = R;
        #dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

        # draw arrow, inlet radial line [x1, y1] to [x2, y2] 
        text = ' Rch = ' + str(R)
        ax.plot(x1, 0, '+', color='k' )
        # draw dimension from [x1, y1] to [x2, y2] 
        ax.annotate( "", [x1, y1], [x2, y2] , arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<-') )
        ax.text((x1+x2)/2, R/2, text, fontsize=9 )  

        # nozzle inlet length line [0,0] to [xe[0], 0]
        text = ' Li = ' + str( round( abs(linex[1]), 1) ) 
        #ax.plot(0,0, '+' )
        # draw dimension from [0,0] to [xe[0], 0]
        ax.annotate( "", [0,0], [linex[1], 0], arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<->') )
        ax.text( linex[1]/2, Rt/15, text, ha='center', fontsize=9 ) 

        global Li 
        Li = abs(linex[1])
            
        # find mid point and draw arc radius
        i = int(len(xe)/2)
        xcenter = 0;    ycenter = 2.5 * Rt;  
        xarch = xe[i];  yarch = ye[i]
        # draw arrow, enterant radial line [xcenter, ycenter] to [xarch, yarch] 
        text = 'Ri = '+ str( round( 1.5 * Rt, 1 ) ) 
        ax.plot(xcenter, ycenter, '+', color='g' )
        # draw dimension from [xcenter, ycenter] to [xarch, yarch]
        ax.annotate( "", [xcenter, ycenter], [xarch, yarch], arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<-') )
        ax.text(Rt/15, ycenter, text, fontsize=9 )
        ###ax.plot(xe2, ye2, linewidth=0.5, color='r')

        # throat radius line [0,0] to [xe[-1], ye[-1]]
        text = ' Rt = '+ str(Rt)
        ax.plot(0, 0, '+', color='r' )
        # draw dimension from [0,0] to [xe[-1], ye[-1]]
        ax.annotate( "", [0,0], [xe[-1], nye[-1]], arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<-') )
        ax.text( xe[-1]/2, nye[-1]/2, text, fontsize=9 )    

        # throat exit
        ax.plot(xe2, ye2, linewidth=2.5, color='r')
        ax.plot(xe2, nye2, linewidth=2.5, color='r')
        # find mid point and draw arc radius
        i = int(len(xe2)/2)
        xcenter2 = 0;   ycenter2 = 1.382 * Rt;  
        xarch2 = xe2[i];  yarch2 = ye2[i]
        # draw arrow, exit radial line from [xcenter2,ycenter2] to [xarch2, yarch2]
        text = 'Rn = '+ str( round(0.382 * Rt,1) ) 
        ax.plot(xcenter2, ycenter2, '+', color='r' )
        # draw dimension from [xcenter2,ycenter2] to [xarch2, yarch2]
        ax.annotate( "", [xcenter2,ycenter2], [xarch2, yarch2], arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<-') )
        ax.text(Rt/15, ycenter2, text, fontsize=9 )

        # bell section
        ax.plot(xbell, ybell, linewidth=2.5, color='b')
        ax.plot(xbell, nybell, linewidth=2.5, color='b')

        # throat radius line [0,0] to [xe[-1], ye[-1]]
        text = ' Re = ' + str( round( (math.sqrt(aratio) * Rt), 1) ) 
        ax.plot(xbell[-1],0, '+', color='blue' )
        # draw dimension from [0,0] to [xe[-1], ye[-1]]
        ax.annotate( "", [xbell[-1],0], [xbell[-1], ybell[-1]], arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<-') )
        ax.text( (xbell[-1] - Rt/15), ybell[-1]/2, text, ha='right', fontsize=9 )   

        # nozzle length line [0,0] to [xe[-1], ye[-1]]
        text = ' Ln = ' + str( round( nozzle_length, 1) ) 
        #ax.plot(0,0, '+' )
        # draw dimension from [0,0] to [xbell[-1], 0]
        ax.annotate( "", [0,0], [xbell[-1], 0], arrowprops=dict(lw=0.5, arrowstyle='<->') )
        ax.text( xbell[-1]/2, Rt/15, text, ha='center', fontsize=9 )    

        # axis
        #ax.axhline(color='black', lw=0.5, linestyle="dashed")
        ax.axvline(color='black', lw=0.5, linestyle="dashed")       
        
        # grids
        ax.grid()
        ax.minorticks_on()
        ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5') # , color='red'
        ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5') # , color='black'    
        
        # show
        plt.title(title, fontsize=9)

        global theta_n_deg 
        theta_n_deg = math.degrees(theta_n)
        global theta_e_deg 
        theta_e_deg = math.degrees(theta_e)
        
        # draw theta_n, throat inflexion angle
        adj_text = 0
        origin  = [ xe2[-1], nye2[-1]-adj_text ]
        degree_symbol = r'$\theta$n'    
        draw_angle_arc(ax, theta_n, origin, degree_symbol )

        # draw theta_n, throat exit angle
        origin  = [ xbell[-1], nybell[-1] ]
        degree_symbol = r'$\theta$e'    
        draw_angle_arc(ax, theta_e, origin, degree_symbol )
        return  
    
    def draw_angle_arc(ax, theta_n, origin, degree_symbol=r'$\theta$'):                 # функция отображения дуги для построения профиля сопла 
        length = 30
        # start point
        startx = origin[0]; starty = origin[1];
        # find the end point
        endx = startx + np.cos(-theta_n) * length #* 0.5
        endy = starty + np.sin(-theta_n) * length #* 0.5
        # draw the angled line / наклонная линия
        ax.plot([startx,endx], [starty,endy], linewidth=0.5, color='k')
        # horizontal line
        ax.hlines(y=starty, xmin=startx, xmax=startx+length, linewidth=0.5, color='k')
        # angle
        #arc_obj = Arc([startx, starty], r1, r1, 0, -math.degrees(theta_n), 0, color='k' )  # попробовать откомментить после отладки
        #ax.add_patch(arc_obj)                                                              # попробовать откомментить после отладки
        ax.text(startx+r1/15, starty+r1/15, degree_symbol + ' = ' + str(round(math.degrees(theta_n),1)) + u"\u00b0")    
        return              
    
    def ring(r, h, a=0, n_theta=30, n_height=10):                                       # ring of radius r, height h, base point a 
        theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_theta)
        v = np.linspace(a, a+h, n_height )
        theta, v = np.meshgrid(theta, v)
        x = r*np.cos(theta)
        y = r*np.sin(theta)
        z = v
        return x, y, z                                  

    def plot(title, throat_radius, angles, contour):                                    # график 
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot()                 
        plot_nozzle(ax1, title, throat_radius, angles, contour)
        fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
        #plt.show()
        plt.clf()
        plt.close()
        return                                  

    #-INPUT MANDATORY DATA---------------------------------------------------

    k = float(ui.doubleSpinBox_45.text().replace(',', '.'))                 # показатель адиабаты
    d1 = float(ui.doubleSpinBox_44.text().replace(',', '.'))                # диаметр критики
    D = float(ui.doubleSpinBox_48.text().replace(',', '.'))                 # диаметр камеры сгорания

    #-CHECK-------------------------------------------------------------------

    if d1 >= D:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Диаметр критического сечения не может быть равен или больше значения диаметра камеры сгорания!")
        return

    if ui.radioButton_2.isChecked(): 

        #-INPUT GEOMETRY DATA----------------------------------------------------     
                 
        d2 = float(ui.doubleSpinBox_46.text().replace(',', '.'))            # диаметр среза сопла

        #-CHECK-------------------------------------------------------------------

        if d1 >= d2:
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Диаметр критического сечения не может быть равен или больше значения диаметра выходного сечения!")
            return   
   
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # initializing variables

        r1 = d1 / 2                                                         # радиус критики
        r2 = d2 / 2                                                         # радиус среза сопла
        R = D / 2                                                           # радиус камеры сгорания
        throat_radius = r1
        aratio = r2**2 / r1**2 
        l_percent = 80                                                      # nozzle length percentage upto the nozzle designer, usually 80
        
        def nc_from_eps_c(p_c, p_e, k):                                     # вычисление геометрической степени расширения сопла от степени расширения по давлению 
    
            FaFkr = ((k + 1) / 2)**(1 / (k - 1)) \
                * (p_e / p_c)**(1 / k) \
                * ((k + 1) / (k - 1)*( 1 - (p_e / p_c)**((k -1) / k)))**0.5
            nc = 1/FaFkr
            return nc

        def eps_c_from_nc(nc, k):                                           # вычисление степени расширения сопла по давлению от геометрической степени расширения
        
            pressure_ratio = fsolve(lambda x: nc - nc_from_eps_c(1., x, k), x0=1e-3 / nc)[0]
            assert pressure_ratio < 1
            return pressure_ratio

        eps_c = 1 / eps_c_from_nc(aratio, k)                                # степень расширения сопла по давлению

        #-CHECK-------------------------------------------------------------------

        if eps_c >= 500:
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Вводимые значение превышают экспериментальный диапазон!")
            return   
   
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
        #------------------------------CALCULATIONS-------------------------------

        angles, contour = bell_nozzle(k, aratio, throat_radius, l_percent)
        
        ui.label_26.setText('')
        ui.label_27.setText('')
        ui.label_28.setText('')
        ui.label_32.setText('')

    elif ui.radioButton_3.isChecked():
 
        #-INPUT PRESSURE DATA----------------------------------------------------
        
        P = float(ui.doubleSpinBox_47.text().replace(',', '.'))             # давление в камере сгорания
        H = float(ui.comboBox.currentText().replace(',', '.'))              # наружное давление
        
        # height to ambient presure / значение наружного давление в зависимости от высоты / берем давление на половине высоты Н из ГОСТ 4401-81
        if H == 1   : P_a =     95461
        if H == 2   : P_a =     89876
        if H == 3   : P_a =     84559.7
        if H == 4   : P_a =     79501
        if H == 5   : P_a =     74692
        if H == 6   : P_a =     70121
        if H == 7   : P_a =     65780
        if H == 8   : P_a =     61660
        if H == 9   : P_a =     57732
        if H == 10  : P_a =     54048
        if H == 11  : P_a =     50539
        if H == 12  : P_a =     47218
        if H == 13  : P_a =     44076
        if H == 14  : P_a =     41105
        if H == 15  : P_a =     38299.7
        if H == 16  : P_a =     35652
        if H == 17  : P_a =     33154
        if H == 18  : P_a =     30801
        if H == 19  : P_a =     28585
        if H == 20  : P_a =     26499.9
        if H == 21  : P_a =     24540
        if H == 22  : P_a =     22699.9
        if H == 23  : P_a =     20985
        if H == 24  : P_a =     19399
        if H == 25  : P_a =     17934
        if H == 26  : P_a =     16579.6
        if H == 27  : P_a =     15328
        if H == 28  : P_a =     14170
        if H == 29  : P_a =     13101
        if H == 30  : P_a =     12112
        if H == 31  : P_a =     11198
        if H == 32  : P_a =     10353
        if H == 33  : P_a =     9572
        if H == 34  : P_a =     8850
        if H == 35  : P_a =     8182
        if H == 36  : P_a =     7565
        if H == 37  : P_a =     6995
        if H == 38  : P_a =     6467
        if H == 39  : P_a =     5980
        if H == 40  : P_a =     5529
        if H == 41  : P_a =     5113
        if H == 42  : P_a =     4730
        if H == 43  : P_a =     4375
        if H == 44  : P_a =     4047
        if H == 45  : P_a =     3746
        if H == 46  : P_a =     3467
        if H == 47  : P_a =     3209
        if H == 48  : P_a =     2972
        if H == 49  : P_a =     2752
        if H == 50  : P_a =     2549
        if H == 51  : P_a =     2362
        if H == 52  : P_a =     2188
        if H == 53  : P_a =     2028
        if H == 54  : P_a =     1880
        if H == 55  : P_a =     1743
        if H == 56  : P_a =     1616
        if H == 57  : P_a =     1499
        if H == 58  : P_a =     1390
        if H == 59  : P_a =     1290
        if H == 60  : P_a =     1197
        if H == 61  : P_a =     1111
        if H == 62  : P_a =     1031
        if H == 63  : P_a =     957
        if H == 64  : P_a =     889
        if H == 65  : P_a =     826
        if H == 66  : P_a =     767
        if H == 67  : P_a =     713
        if H == 68  : P_a =     663
        if H == 69  : P_a =     617
        if H == 70  : P_a =     575
        if H == 71  : P_a =     535
        if H == 72  : P_a =     499
        if H == 73  : P_a =     465
        if H == 74  : P_a =     433
        if H == 75  : P_a =     404
        if H == 76  : P_a =     377
        if H == 77  : P_a =     352
        if H == 78  : P_a =     329
        if H == 79  : P_a =     307
        if H == 80  : P_a =     287
        if H == 81  : P_a =     268
        if H == 82  : P_a =     251
        if H == 83  : P_a =     235
        if H == 84  : P_a =     220
        if H == 85  : P_a =     206
        if H == 86  : P_a =     193
        if H == 87  : P_a =     181
        if H == 88  : P_a =     169
        if H == 89  : P_a =     159
        if H == 90  : P_a =     149
        if H == 91  : P_a =     140
        if H == 92  : P_a =     131
        if H == 93  : P_a =     123
        if H == 94  : P_a =     116
        if H == 95  : P_a =     109
        if H == 96  : P_a =     102
        if H == 97  : P_a =     96
        if H == 98  : P_a =     90
        if H == 99  : P_a =     85
        if H == 100 : P_a =     80
                
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # initializing variables

        r1 = d1 / 2                                                         # радиус критики
        R = D / 2                                                           # радиус камеры сгорания
        throat_radius = r1
        l_percent = 80                                                      # nozzle length percentage upto the nozzle designer, usually 80
        eps_c = P / P_a

        #-CHECK-------------------------------------------------------------------

        if eps_c >= 500:
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Вводимые значение превышают экспериментальный диапазон!")
            return   
   
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
        #------------------------------CALCULATIONS-------------------------------

        FaFkr = ((k + 1) / 2)**(1 / (k - 1)) * (P_a / P)**(1 / k) * ((k + 1) / (k - 1)*( 1 - (P_a / P)**((k - 1) / k)))**0.5
        aratio = 1/FaFkr
        r2 = (aratio * r1 * r1)**0.5

        angles, contour = bell_nozzle(k, aratio, throat_radius, l_percent)

        ui.label_26.setText('Давление на срезе (Па):')
        ui.label_27.setText('Диаметр выходного сечения (м):')
        ui.label_28.setText(str(round(P_a, 2)))
        ui.label_32.setText(str(round(r2*2, 2)))

    #-PLOT-------------------------------------------------------------------

    title = 'Оптимизированное по тяге сопло, профилированное по методу Рао (метод парабол)' 
    plot(title, throat_radius, angles, contour)

    ui.label_19.setText(str(round(Li, 2)))
    ui.label_35.setText(str(round(len_nozzle, 2)))
    ui.label_34.setText(str(round(aratio, 2)))
    ui.label_29.setText(str(round(eps_c, 2)))
    ui.label_31.setText(str(round(theta_n_deg, 2)))
    ui.label_33.setText(str(round(theta_e_deg, 2)))
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Так как самого интерфейса вы не предоставили, вот вам мой небольшой пример:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt6 import uic
import io

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Инициализация пользовательского интерфейса
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        
        # Загружаем разметку UI из строки
        ui_string = '''
        <ui version="4.0">
         <class>MainWindow</class>
         <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
          <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="button1">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Button 1</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="button2">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Button 2</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
         </widget>
         <resources/>
         <connections/>
        </ui>
        '''

        # Загружаем UI из строки с использованием loadUiType
        Ui_MainWindow, _ = uic.loadUiType(io.StringIO(ui_string))
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Подключаем слоты (обработчики событий) к сигналам нажатия кнопок
        self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_button1_clicked)
        self.ui.button2.clicked.connect(self.on_button2_clicked)
        self.ui.button2.setEnabled(False)

    def on_button1_clicked(self):
        # Делаем кнопку 2 активной и кнопку 1 неактивной
        self.ui.button1.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.button2.setEnabled(True)

    def on_button2_clicked(self):
        # Делаем кнопку 1 активной и кнопку 2 неактивной
        self.ui.button1.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.button2.setEnabled(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```